# SQL: how to select values that are LIKE at least one value from CTE

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-like, contains, with-statement

I created a CTE of distinct string values and I want to select from dataset only values (strings) that contains at least one of strings from the CTE.
I need some kind of **in** *multiple* **like** from CTE.

Example:

say we have @data_1, @data_2 and CTE

*with CTE as (
select distinct words
from @data_1
)*

I want to select only values from @data_2 that contains at least one of the words in the CTE.

if CTE contains:
'one',
'two',
'three'

and @data_2 contains: 'one hundred', 'two thousend', 'thirty'

SELECT only the values- 'one hundred', 'two thousend'

Is there a way to do that (with use of CTE and not LIKE singular values)?
Thanks

Comment: Post a data sample and desired output (as text).

Comment: added an example, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
WHERE table_column_name = CTE_column_name
```

NB: if there were duplicates in the CTE this would return duplicate rows.